# how to fix an overlay at end-of-line highlighting too much?

Tags: mark, overlays

I have added the following definitions to my initialization file in order to make the mark show up as a red highlight:

```
(defface mmv-face
  '((t :inherit default :background "red"))
  "Face used for showing the mark's position.")

(defvar mmv-mark-overlay nil "Overlay for showing the mark's position.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'mmv-mark-overlay)

;; The three optional arguments are needed to cover the optional arguments of
;; those functions that this function will modify through `advice-add'.
(defun mmv-show-mark (&optional ARG1 ARG2 ARG3)
  "Make the mark's position stand out by means of a one-character-long overlay."
  (unless mmv-mark-overlay
    (setq mmv-mark-overlay (make-overlay 0 0 nil t))
    (overlay-put mmv-mark-overlay 'face 'mmv-face))
  (let ((mark-position (mark t)))
    (when mark-position
      ; Function `mark' returns non-nil only if the buffer's mark is set, so
      ; doing the following is pointless if `mark-position' is nil.
      (move-overlay mmv-mark-overlay mark-position (1+ mark-position)))))

(advice-add 'set-mark :after #'mmv-show-mark)
(advice-add 'pop-mark :after #'mmv-show-mark)
(advice-add 'push-mark :after #'mmv-show-mark)
```

It works well otherwise, except that if the mark is at the end of a line, everything to the right of the mark is also highlighted; see the screenshot below. Why would this be, and how can it be fixed?

[image: Screenshot of a mark at end-of-line generating excessive highlighting]

Comment: How about testing for a line end `\n` / `10` and if so, then don't place an overlay spanning that line-end?  Alternatively, for line ends you could use a floating overlay with the `after-string` property -- in which case the overlay would not span a full point, but rather the BEG/END would be the same point.  You can set the width of a floating overlay `after-string` too.

Comment: Why `:inherit default` ?

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the suggestion. Stefan's answer uses the `after-string` property.

Comment: @Stefan That was part of code I copied (from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MakingMarkVisible) and then edited to arrive at the present code. It seems it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a face is placed on a newline (aka "LF") character, Emacs highlights the whole "rest of the line".  That's why (in your case when the mark is at EOL, `mark-position` is just before LF and `(1+ mark-position)` is just after).

As for how to fix it, I think you'll want to do something like:

```
(defface mmv-face
  '((t :background "red"))
  "Face used for showing the mark's position.")

(defvar-local mmv-mark-overlay nil "Overlay for showing the mark's position.")

(defun mmv-show-mark (&rest _)
  "Make the mark's position stand out by means of a one-character-long overlay."
  (unless mmv-mark-overlay
    (setq mmv-mark-overlay (make-overlay 0 0 nil t))
    (overlay-put mmv-mark-overlay 'face 'mmv-face))
  (let ((mark-position (mark t)))
    (cond
     ((null mark-position) (delete-overlay mmv-mark-overlay))
     ((and (< mark-position (point-max))
           (not (eq ?\n (char-after mark-position))))
      (overlay-put mmv-mark-overlay 'after-string nil)
      (move-overlay mmv-mark-overlay
                    mark-position (1+ mark-position)))
     (t
      ;; This branch is called when the mark is at the end of a line or at the
      ;; end of the buffer. We use a bit of trickery to avoid the higlight
      ;; extending from the mark all the way to the right end of the frame.
      (overlay-put mmv-mark-overlay 'after-string
                   (propertize " " 'face (overlay-get mmv-mark-overlay 'face)))
      (move-overlay mmv-mark-overlay
                    mark-position mark-position)))))

(add-hook 'pre-redisplay-functions #'mmv-show-mark)
```

Note that this also takes care of removing the overlay when/if the mark is removed (this normally never happens, but we may as well), as well as handle the EOB case.

Two more things:

1. You can use `defvar-local`.
2. Rather than `&optional ARG1 ARG2 ARG3` you're better doing `&rest _` to simply accept any number of arguments and say that you'll ignore them.
3. Rather than advise an ever growing number of commands that can move/activate the mark, you should likely use

   ```
   (add-hook 'pre-redisplay-functions #'mmv-show-mark)
   ```

   this is the same hook normally used to highlight the region.

Comment: In most of your code that I have seen over the years, you do not use point and point+1 for an `after-string`; but rather you have used point/point.  Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: @lawlist: the `after-string` is displayed at the `overlay-end` position and is unaffected by the `overlay-start` position (unless you set `evaporate` on the overlay, in which case start==end will delete the overlay).